# creacion de celda con link route en datatable

Tags: laravel, ajax, datatables

Estoy usando laravel 8, y datatables Estaba creando una tabla con datos que venian de una base de datos, y luego con un foreach creaba cada fila de la tabla entre ellas un boton para ir al detalle de cada producto.

Como estos productos van a crecer mucho en tiempo muy corto, decidí usar datatables, del lado del servidor,
es asi que la carga se hace muchisimo mas rapio, pero me encontré un problema a la hora de crear una de las celdas.

para la primera celda me cree sin problema la imagen, asi:

```
data: 'url',
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            $(nTd).html("<img style='width: 100px; height: 100px;' src='"+oData.url+"' />" );              
            }
```

el codigo final me imprime asi, ya que la variable url contiene el link.

```
 <img style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" src="https://sitio.com.co/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/10009.jpg">
```

pero cuando intento crear la parte del boton:

```
data: 'cod',
             "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            $(nTd).html("<a  class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='{{route('producto.catego.final'," +oData.cod+" )}}' role='button'> Ver Productos </a>" );              
            }
```

Esta no me interpreta el oData que deberia ser el "id" del producto, ya que la variable "cod" me contiene el id del producto, "1" o "2" o "3" etc. y me imprime el link asi:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="http://localhost/project/public/productoscatego/%20+oData.cod+" role="button"> Ver Productos </a>
```

No se como podria construir esa celda, para que en me ponga el valor del id ahi, este es el codigo en html que me funcionaba antes y ahora inteto replicar:

```
<a  class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="{{route('producto.catego.final', $categoria->cod)}}" role="button"> Ver Productos </a>
```

Este codigo anterior me imprimia el siguiente codigo sin problemas:

```
https://sitio.com/public/productoscatego/1
https://sitio.com/public/productoscatego/2
https://sitio.com/public/productoscatego/3
https://sitio.com/public/productoscatego/4  .... etc
```

Desde mi controlador yo envio mis datos de la siguiente manera:

```
return datatables(Producto::query())->toJson();
```

a continuacion expongo todo mi ajax:

```
$('#example1').DataTable({
      "serverSide" : true,
      "procesing" : true,
    //   order: [[2, "desc"]],
      "ajax" : "{{ route('cate.api') }}",
      "columns" :[
        
        { 
            data: 'url',
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            $(nTd).html("<img style='width: 100px; height: 100px;' src='"+oData.url+"' />" );              
            } 

         } ,
        { data: 'categoria' } ,
        {
             data: 'cod',
             "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
            $(nTd).html("<a  class='btn btn-outline-primary' href='{{route('producto.catego.final','" +oData.cod+"' )}}' role='button'> Ver Productos </a>" );              
            } 
        } ,        
      ]
      
    });
```

Tando el oData.url como el oData.cod, son valores que vienen desde el backend.
todo mi js esta en dentro de un $( document ).ready().
para que este se ejecute despues de cargar la pagina.

url y cod, son atributos que contiene mi producto, y vienen desde el backend.

Podria alguien ayudarme a entener por que en esta parte no me imprime el valor de oData.url, en cambio me lo deja plano el texto? y como podria yo corregir esto? muchas gracias.

Comment: tu JS invoca la función cuando se dibuja la página, y para llegar a eso PHP tiene que haber terminado su trabajo de renderización. Debieras simplemente concatenar, al igual que en la imágen, desde javascript, o enviar la url del href desde el backend